# Remove newline in specific pattern, but "slash" disappeared

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file like this (much whitespace left at the beginning of each line):

```
    2016/03/01
               6,015,511 +0.55 3,718
    2016/03/02
               4,584,160 -0.50 2,885
    2016/03/03
               5,509,856 0.00 718
```

The goals is to remove the newline after the date string such as in

```
    2016/03/01        6,015,511 +0.55 3,718
    2016/03/02        4,584,160 -0.50 2,885
    2016/03/03        5,509,856 0.00 718
```

Using

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s:\([[:digit:]]\S*\)\n:\1 :g'
```

results in all lines combined into one line.

Adding a slash to the regex to remove the newline in the date string

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s:\/\([[:digit:]]\S*\)\n:\1 :g'
```

Result is (first slash in date string is disappeared):

```
    201603/01        6,015,511 +0.55 3,718
    201603/02        4,584,160 -0.50 2,885
    201603/03        5,509,856 0.00 718
```

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Do your files really start with a blank line, or is that an artefact of using html tags? You can create blocks of code by indenting it four spaces (or selecting it, then pressing Ctrl + K).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you want is this:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n//' infile
    2016/03/01               6,015,511 +0.55 3,718
    2016/03/02               4,584,160 -0.50 2,885
    2016/03/03               5,509,856 0.00 718
```

This adds the next line to the pattern space, then removes the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try following script:

```
sed 's/^\s*//;N;s/\n\s*/    /' data.txt 

2016/03/01    6,015,511 +0.55 3,718
2016/03/02    4,584,160 -0.50 2,885
2016/03/03    5,509,856 0.00 718
```

It remove all leading spaces from first line and insert reasonable spaces between first and second line.

Comment: Thanks Saleem's reply. It removes not only newline but leading whitespace.